# MatLab - Newton's method algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matlab, newtons-method

I have written the following algorithm in order to evaluate a function in MatLab using Newton's method (we set r = -7 in my solution):

```
function newton(r);
syms x;
y = exp(x) - 1.5 - atan(x);
yprime = diff(y,x);
f = matlabFunction(y);
fprime = matlabFunction(yprime);
x = r;
xvals = x
for i=1:8 
    u = x;
    x = u - f(r)/fprime(r);
    xvals = x
end
```

The algorithm works in that it runs without any errors, but the numbers keep decreasing at every iteration, even though, according to my textbook, the expression should converge to roughly -14 for x.  My algorithm is correct the first two iterations, but then it goes beyond -14 and finally ends up at roughøy -36.4 after all iterations have completed.

If anyone can give me some help as to why the algorithm does not work properly, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think

```
x = u - f(r)/fprime(r);
```

should be

```
x = u - f(u)/fprime(u);
```

If you always use `r`, you're always decrementing `x` by the same value.

Comment: Awesome!  Now it works like a charm, and, of course, I see now that your answer is how the formula should be written :).  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
syms x
y = exp(x) - 1.5 - atan(x); % your function is converted in for loop
x=-1;
n=10;
v=0;
for i=2:n
    x(i)=tan(exp(x(i-1))-1.5);
    v=[v ;x(i)]; % you will get solution vector  for each i value
end
v
```